# _cvLoadImage undefined symbols linking issue

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, deep-learning, linker-flags

i am compiling conv-net (http://conv-net.sourceforge.net/) deep learning library opencv and c++ on my mac osx and i cant seem to get through this error. This seems to be a linking issue. All the opencv libraries are compiled for 64 bit, i tried setting -m64 flag in cmake, nope still not working.

I dont know which library _cvLoadImage() links into??? i am linking properly to proper libraries but cant fix this one error?????

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_cvLoadImage", referenced from:
      _main in testimg.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [testimg] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/testimg.dir/all] Error 2
```

i did a -v output of the linker and it shows this...

```
Linking CXX executable testimg
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Thread model: posix
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.10.0 -o testimg -search_paths_first -headerpad_max_install_names CMakeFiles/testimg.dir/tst/testimg.cpp.o libcvconvnet.a -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lexpat -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_photo -lopencv_shape -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/6.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
```

Comment: `cvLoadImage()` is found in the HighGUI module. Do you know where you installed OpenCV, and if so can you run `nm /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.dylib | grep cvLoadImage` (or similar; change the path appropriately) and tell us if you get something similar to `0000000000016ef0 T _cvLoadImage`?

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Add that comment as an answer.

Comment: @karlphillip But it's not an answer... All I was saying is that's in HighGUI and that command only checks whether the symbol is defined in the library! It doesn't fix anything and change anything!

Answer (score 3):

In opencv 3.1.0 I wasn't able to find the missing symbols in `/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.dylib` but rather in `/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.dylib`.

So add `-lopencv_imgcodecs` to your compilation command.